# move file windows xp

Tags: cmd, windows-xp-sp3

> Im trying to move file in Windows xp using CMD

```
move C:\Test.pdf %userprofile%\Desktop
```

> It says the syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Is there a space in `%userprofile%`? Best pracitce: quote folder/file names: `move "C:\Test.pdf" "%userprofile%\Desktop\"`

Comment: It is a best practice to always quote paths.